# Excel "IFS" criteria values using cell references

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

My data consists of a month column A (1 through 12) and a values column B (financial returns) spanning multiple years. How do I count the number of month occurrences in the second half of the year with positive returns?

Let's also say I have values 1 through 12 in a third column C

A formula like this does not seem to work:

=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$999, ">0", $A$2:$A$999, **">=C6"**)

C6 simply equals the number 6.
I can't seem to pass on boolean/inequality values into the ifs criteria using a cell reference. How do I get around this? I tried removing quotes and using the & but still no luck.

Column B = Returns,
Column A = Months (1-12),
Column C = 1 through 12 (to present a table of counts).

Thanks for any help! Much appreciated!

Comment: remove the reference from th quotes and concatenate: `">=" & C6`

Comment: To maintain consistency, you might want to change `">0"` to `">"&0`. It isn't absolutely necessary but it would make future editing more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

First let me explain that why you are getting as error using the Formula,,

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$999, ">0", $A$2:$A$999, ">=C6")
```

- Reason, the command syntax is wrong with second part.

  `$A$2:$A$999, ">=C6")`
- Which should written like  `$A$2:$A$999, ">="&C6)`,, as also been
  pointed by few readers through comments above.

---

*Now let me show you the correct formula to use.*

- If you use this:

  ```
  =COUNTIFS($H$27:$H$35, ">0", $G$27:$G$35, ">="&J26)
  ```

or even,,

```
=COUNTIFS($H$27:$H$35, ">"&0, $G$27:$G$35, ">"&J26)
```

[image]

You get `5` (cell `I27`), since the formula fails to consider data in Range `H27:H35`, are `>0` (or Positive value).

**N.B.** Even any Array formula (CSE) fails to do so,, also including this  `">"&0`.

---

**Now, check the Formula in Cell `J27`, gets correct count.**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(MONTH(G27:G35)>J$26)*(H27:H35>0))
```

[image]

*You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: a) The OP clearly states *'data consists of a month column A (1 through 12)'*. Your COUNTIFS only works because the dates are all greater than `06-Jan-1900` (*aka* 6). b) You're using `">"&J26` in the COUNTIFS but `>J$26` in the SUMPRODUCT.

Comment: @Jeeped,, thanks for observation,,, OP wants to count all Row/Cells have date greater than JUNE ,,, along with +ve values ,,, with shown example dates are genuine and in `MM/DD/YY` format,,, with `Counifs` allowed syntax is '">"&J26 but what matters is the operator and is `>` in both functions!